# one-line Perl script: add a whitespace after digits

Tags: perl, whitespace

I have a file full of lines that look like this:

```
 D50541CGGAUCGUAAAGCUCUGUUGUUAGAGAAGAACAGCGCAUAGAGUAACUGC
 AB303221GAGUUAAUCGUCUUGAAGGUACCUGAAGAGGAAGCCCCGGCUAACUCC
 AJ812213AGGGAACAAGGCUAGUUUGCUAGUUGAGGGUACCUGCAGAAGAAGCAC
```

I'm trying to insert 1 whitespace character after the string of digits for each line, here's my attempt (test2.txt is the filename of the file I'm working with):

```
 perl -pe 's/(\w+\d+)\s(.+)/' test2.txt
```

It doesn't work (I get the error `Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1`, but this is what I want my output to look like:

```
 D50541 CGGAUCGUAAAGCUCUGUUGUUAGAGAAGAACAGCGCAUAGAGUAACUGC
 AB303221 GAGUUAAUCGUCUUGAAGGUACCUGAAGAGGAAGCCCCGGCUAACUCC
 AJ812213 AGGGAACAAGGCUAGUUUGCUAGUUGAGGGUACCUGCAGAAGAAGCAC
```

I'm just learning perl, and it's magical that you can do one line scripts, but mine is not working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were missing the middle forward slash: `s///`.
You only need to replace digits, not letters and digits.
The right side should not be a regular expression.

```
 perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1 /' test2.txt
```

[Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)